# Kenmore washing machine stuck at sense cycle with drum bashing against side walls

Tags: repair, washing-machine

For a while now the spin cycle has seemingly got ever so more loud. I removed the surround to the tub which looks to be for fabric softener to drip into it and then into the double wall of the bowl, which lessened the issue for a while. Now the sense cycle (with lid lock bypassed such as I can observe the bowl during the operation of the washer) has the drum start spinning balanced but within a second spins out more and more, stops and then starts a few seconds later, and is stuck in this cycle.

Diagnostic mode shows that a test wash, rinse and spin cycle still completes without error.

I have replaced the supports that connect the drum to the body, with no change in symptoms.

I have seen others suggest online there might be an issue with the gears, bearings, etc, but they don't elaborate on how that can be the issue (parts for my washer seem to be scarce, but am technically minded and up for the challenge to repair instead of replace), and even better pictures of what part of these components is causing this issue.

Can take a video of the symptom if this would be helpful to anyone to understand the issue better.

Comment: I don't think it has anything wrong other than a heavier/denser cloth was mixed with the other much lighter clothes and spun out of balance, or the washer was overloaded. It occurs to all my washers.

Comment: @r13 - I am sure we have washed heavy items before and this is the first time it won't progress past the sense stage, through multiple unplugging of washing machine, taking out and repositioning load contents, etc.

Comment: The fault is not the heavy load, it is the unbalanced load that causing the drum to bang on the side walls while spinning. At this time, if you have reloaded the clothes evenly, and the washer still won't work, then I guess you might have a faulty control module that couldn't reset itself.

Comment: @r13 - First it was a "heavier/denser cloth was mixed with the other much lighter clothes" (a weight issue), now it is an unbalanced load (not the case, I spent much time evenly distributing a test load with one weight and type of fabric), and now it is a faulty control module because somehow the control module has control over how the drum moves in the horizontal plane, without any electro-mechanical parts to enable it to do so. The sense cycle is spinning in exactly the same way I am used to. This can't be it, and I am not going to source a whole new control board based on this assumption.

Comment: It was my experience to share. You surely shouldn't jump out to get the module based on someone's guess before verified by a technician. Good luck.

Comment: Sounds like  bad bearings to me. I had a front loading washer that eventually got so loud that if we were doing laundry when guests were over, some asked what the heck is that noise? LOL  It was old enough (and one of those problematic front loading Maytags involved in multiple class action law suits) that we just replaced it with a top loader.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson - Thanks. Hopefully someone comes along that has taken apart and perhaps rebuilt the bearings, to at least help identify that as the issue and possibly also guide me through the process.

Comment: You've looked for broken suspension springs? Disconnected springs now lying down in the nether regions of the washer?

Comment: @MTA - If by springs you mean the ones on the rods that connect the drum to the case, they are brand new (first troubleshooting step).